# Parse Installation Table not registering deviceToken

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, devicetoken

I have followed the standard procedure for registering a deviceToken on a user installation:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

This callback is triggered and when I breakpoint through, the device token in there (as 32bit NSData). The installation is refreshed, but no device token is recorded.

I've had this successfully working before, and it actually works every now and then, however there appears to be no consistency.

I expect that it is something to do with provisioning profiles. However I have tried using Xcode's automatic profiles (with explicit bundle id), re-making my own, trying adHoc, release, renewing my SSL certificates, re-exporting and re-uploading them to Parse.

The last time I tried, 1 device of 3 successfully registered a deviceToken. Another device built from the same machine with the same provisioning profile (an iPad) failed to register it however. I copied the same provisioning profile to my current machine, however the deviceToken still failed to register.

I call this in didFinishLaunchinWithOptions

```
- (void)registerForNotifications
{
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes  categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

I see that [Parse.com deviceToken and PFInstallation not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116849/parse-com-devicetoken-and-pfinstallation-not-saved) is having a similar issue. Parse Framework issue perhaps? I'm on 1.7.5.

Comment: nb - setting the device token to @"" as suggested in the other question worked. So it seems setDeviceTokeFromData does not work for an uninitialised deviceToken. Or works, but very occasionally!

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that the deviceToken doesn't appear to update if you're running off the debugger... Running standalone however, does.